# Define a PHP array() with the contents of an included file.

Tags: php, arrays, include

I'm trying to figure out how to define an array with the contents of another file. Is it possible? If yes, can you help point me in the right direction?

**Current Array**

```
array(
        '
        html code
        ',
        '
        html code
        ',
        '
    );
```

**Desired Array**

```
array(
     include "arrays/htmlCode.php"; 
    );
```

**Contents of htmlCode.php file**

```
        '
        html code
        ',
        '
        html code
        ',
        '
```

**Results of Code**

```
include "arrays/htmlCode.php";   // gives me an error

include "arrays/htmlCode.php"  //imports the code from htmlCode.php, but it 
                               //isn't recognized as an array. The page 
                               //displays a ' in front and a ', after each item.
```

Comment: With `file_get_contents`?

Comment: why dont you use namespacing

Comment: Get rid of the quotes and commas in the file and then just use `file()`.

Comment: you should just keep the file name in an array and when require you should loop and do `file_get_contents` or `require` it based on your requirement.

Comment: Can it be `array('html code', 'html code',);`, then just append the new lines on the output? If so use `file` and put `html code` on their own lines.

Comment: No luck with any of the above so far. FYI - I've learned 100% of my php knowledge from StackOverFlow and I'm not a professional developer. I'm an occasional weekend warrior. Any additional guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file htmlCode.php is delimited by comma(,), then use :

```
$array = explode(',', file_get_contents('arrays/htmlCode.php'));
```

If you have to check comma(,) in newline or certain pattern to distinguish array elements, use regular expression.

Comment: Thanks Arjun. I was reading another SO post about this solution and then I saw your reply. I was doing it the 'long way', your example was very helpful and saved a few lines of code too. Thanks everyone that replied!